# Вывод не пустых значений

Tags: c, массивы

Заполняю большой массив строками и хочу вывести не пустые значения.

```
#define RECIPE_ARRAY_LENGTH 5000
#define RECIPE_TITLE_LENGTH 64

char aRecipes[RECIPE_ARRAY_LENGTH][RECIPE_TITLE_LENGTH];

//код заполнения массива

int j;
int rowCount = sizeof(aRecipes) / sizeof(aRecipes[0]);
for (j = 0; j < rowCount; j++){
        printf("aRecipes array - %s\n", aRecipes[j]);
}
```

Как подсчитать количество не пустых строк в `rowCount`?Си знаю плохо, поэтому прошу извинить.

Comment: А что такое "пустые строки" или "пустые значения"?

Comment: 1. `rowCount` будет равен `RECIPE_ARRAY_LENGTH`, зачем переменная? 2. А что вы хотели сказать вот этим: `printf(..., aRecipes[j]);`?

Comment: @0andriy,1) по задумке хотел в ней хранить количество не пустых строк.2)Вывести значение строки.

Comment: @KoVadim логично предположить, что строка, имеющая первым байтом не 0 - не пустая.

Comment: Если это учебная задача, то требуется сделать ровно то, что в вопросе. Вам ответили. Если не учебная, то пустые строки можно сразу пропускать, а не пустые считать при получении их откуда бы то ни было.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если непустая строка это любая строка, у которой первый символ не `'\0'` (а это обычно так для классических сишных нуль-терминированных строк), то количество можно определить довольно просто:

```
int j;
int cnt = 0;
for (j = 0; j < RECIPE_ARRAY_LENGTH; j++){
        cnt += *aRecipes[j] ? 1 : 0;
}
```